# If simple linear regression model is valid model for a dataset, the plot of the standardized residuals versus the fitted values's approximately linear

Tags: regression, self-study, mathematical-statistics, linear-model, standardization

I have to decide if the sentence is true or false and then explain why.

''If the simple linear regression model is a valid model for a dataset, the
plot of the standardized residuals versus the fitted values is approximately
linear.''

I think it is true but i am not use and i do not know how to justify this.

Any help would be usefull

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Consider the properties of a simple regression model. Your model assumptions are (1) there is a **linear** relationship between a covariate (predictor) $x$ and a response variable $Y$; (2) all observations are **independent** and identically distributed; (3) the *residuals* or *errors* are **normally** distributed; (4) the errors have **equal variance**. These modeling assumptions can be remembered using the acronym ***LINE***.

Depending on how your course is being taught, you may see observations of the response variable $Y$ written such that
$$
y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \epsilon,\qquad \epsilon \overset{i.i.d}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2),\qquad i=1,2,\dots,N, \tag{1}
$$
for an (generally) unknown but constant variance $\sigma^2$. Equation (1) is sometimes called a model equation. Alternatively, but equivalently, you may write equation (1) in matrix form as $Y = X\beta + \epsilon$. Using the first equation, and noting $x_i$ is considered a constant, taking expectations on both sides of the model gives
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(y_i | x_i) &= \mathbb{E}(\beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \epsilon) \\\\
&= \mathbb{E}(\beta_0) + x_i\mathbb{E}(\beta_1) + \mathbb{E}(\epsilon) \qquad (\text{why?})\\\\
&= \beta_0 + \beta_1x.
\end{align}
Of course when we want to actually find parameter estimates for $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$, we solve the normal equations to obtain estimates $\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_1$. Then we can calculate fitted values $\hat{y}_i = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 x_i$. Interestingly, we can show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N} \hat{\epsilon_i} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} y_i - \hat{y_i} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} y_i - (\hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1x) = 0$$
using the assumption that $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon) = 0$. But we can also write
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N} y_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \hat{y}_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{N} \hat{\epsilon}_i^2\ ,\qquad \sum_{i=1}^{N}\hat{\epsilon}_i^2 \geqslant 0. \tag{2}
$$
Also note that the coefficient of variation, $R^2$ is defined as a ratio of the explained variation in $\hat{y}$ and the total variation in $y$. In the instance where there is an exact relationship between the covariates and the response, the error term in (2) is equal to zero and $R^2 = 1$. For real data, this would never be the case.

How does all of this help you? If all of the initial assumptions we made writing equation (1) were reasonable, the estimates for each $\beta_i$ are unbiased, and the fitted values and the regression line should follow the observed data closely. Said differently there is a linear relationship between the covariates $x$ and the response variable $y$ and the fitted values $\hat{y}$.

In sum, I have tried to build a persuavive argument for why the original claim is false. Specifically, the linear relationship modeled in regression is between the response variable and the covariates. The error term is what makes the data variable, and after we fit the model we have estimates $\hat{\epsilon}$ of the estimand $\epsilon$. Two references that you may also find helpful to review are [Anscombe's Quartet on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet) and [The original paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2682899?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

#### Errata

Removing the statement

> But if this is the case, the residuals $\hat{\epsilon}$ should be
>   identically distributed to the residuals we postulated in model (1).
>   That is, $\hat{\epsilon} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$.

because it is false. (Thank you Cagdas Ozgenc for pointing out the mistake!) A Wikipedia link gives more information on this, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals#Regressions).

Comment: Residuals are not identically distributed, errors are.

Comment: so is it false?

Comment: From danjdrennan's answer i understand that it is true but if Cagdas is correct, then it is false... i am confused

Comment: The claim in the question is definitely false. I've made a mistake declaring the residuals are i.i.d, which ill note in the original posting. But the main point you should get is that the residuals should appear to be random after fitting. If the errors have any kind of trend, then you've miss specified the model in some way (violating one or more assumptions in paragraph 1).